# Amazon Redshift public database

Tags: amazon-redshift

We would like to test some code against Redshift jdbc driver without the hassle to create our own instance.

Is there a public instace of Redshift available for developement testing ?

Comment: They do have 2 month trial http://aws.amazon.com/redshift/free-trial/

Comment: Thanks Andrey, if you put this as an answer I could answer it.

Answer (score 3):

Public instance is not available.

You can create test cluster ( single node) using smallest possible box ( **dw2.large $0.25 per hour** ) and test your code with cluster and terminate it once done.

S

Answer (score 1):

With some limitations, Redshift is basically a Postgres database, so for basic development you can use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift does not have a public instance. But they do provide 2 months of trial period free. You can get 750 hours of usage with node type DC1.Large.

However, there is a site where you can play around with different databases (but Redshift has not been added there yet):

http://sqlfiddle.com/